# My Galaxy J7 phone is not connecting to the Internet without WiFi anymore, anything I can test / verify to make it work?

Tags: mobile-data, samsung-galaxy-j7, t-mobile

What would be the reasons for which my Android would not connect to the Internet using the Mobile Data mode? (that open is ON)

I don't go out much these days since there is Covid, but I'd like to have Internet once in a while and somehow the Mobile Data doesn't seem to connect, yet I can do phone calls just fine. It's it using the same connection for data?

I do have a data plan in good standing and it definitely worked before (last time I can say I tried was some time last summer, so about 6 months ago).

Any idea what I could try next?

Comment: Probably a problem with Access Point configuration. Since you mentioned Tmobile, have a look at this : https://www.t-mobile.com/support/devices/android/t-mobile-revvl/network-apn-and-volte-t-mobile-revvl

Comment: @KaranRajBaruah I've seen that info on my phone, I now compared with the data on that page, it's mostly equal. I would imagine that it's set automatically? Oh and also I can't edit the info anyway, so you'd hope it is automatic... :-)